# Unable to imap Ctrl-Shift-U in gvim

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to bind Ctrl-Shift-U in gvim so that it enters a template text that I frequently need. For example:

```
imap <C-S-u> foo
```

This does not work at all, if I do this, it changes from INSERT mode to "IM INSERT" mode which I have never seen before. So it seems C-S-u is already bound to something, but I cannot figure out how to unbind it. If I say

```
unmap <C-S-u>
```

I get `E31: No such mapping`.

My mapping works just fine with `<C-S-l>`, but I want `<C-S-u>` for this. How do I find out what `<C-S-u>` is bound to and how to unbind it so I can reuse it for my purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use GTK Vim and GTK implements its own **i**nput **m**odule (see what **IM** INSERT means?) [which enters "Unicode mode" on Ctrl+Shift+U](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.IMContext.html).

You can disable the GTK input module by launching Gvim with

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=xim gvim
```

at which point your desired map will take effect.

For more details, see [my answer to *Disable transient symbols for compose and dead keys in GTK programs*](https://linux.codidact.com/posts/285653/285654#answer-285654).